# Log4j Logs are not coming in the pattern I have specified in log4j.properties

Tags: log4j

I am trying to log messages to console using `Log4j`.

I have a class like below

```
public class Demo {
private static Employee employee=null;
private static Logger logger=Logger.getRootLogger();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
    if(employee!=null){
        System.out.println(employee);
    }else{
        logger.warn("Employee object is null in Demo class main method in if(){} statement");
    }
}
}
```

I have `log4j.properties` file in the Project folder. If I keep `log4j.properties` file in `classpath` I am getting file not found exception , so I kept it in Project folder.My project in eclipse is like below

[image]

`log4j.properties` file is as below

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, lntLogger
log4j.appender.lntLogger=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.lntLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c - %m  --date %d{dd MMM yyyy} %n
```

Now I am expecting output in the format `%-4r [%t] %-5p %c - %m  --date %d{dd MMM yyyy} %n`

But I am getting Only my message in the console like

`Employee object is null in Demo class main method in if(){} statement`

Now my question is why my log is not coming in the format what I have specified in properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `log4j.properties` file change 4th line to

```
log4j.appender.lntLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c - %m  --date %d{dd MMM yyyy} %n
```